# How to prepare for future URL rewriting to a directory type structure?

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

So I wish to implement URL rewrite once my site is done but I wish to have it in this format.
`site.com/city/example-deal`

Currently once a city is chosen it links to a page in the following format: 
`site.com/city.php?city=atlanta`

Then once on that page, a deal is selected from there and it links to the next page:
`site.com/deal.php?deal=123`

With that in mind, could I rewrite it as such with my current linking structure:
`site.com/atlanta/example-deal` or do I have to link the page as such:
`site.com/city.php?city=atlanta/deal.php?deal=123` in order to get the final URL rewrite structure I'm looking for.

Hopefully I explained this right and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is so that deal.php reads in the city in the query string.

You should also slugify your deal as well so that you can derive the deal id from the deal slug.

Here's an example of a slugify function in php:

http://sourcecookbook.com/en/recipes/8/function-to-slugify-strings-in-php

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.^/]+)/deals/(.*)$ deal.php?city=$1&deal_slug=<deal_slug> [QSA]
```

Also your deal table in MySQL should be modified to store the slug.  With that your deal.php can be modified so that:

```
// get deal slug from query string

//select from deal table where deal slug = submitted deal slug

// continue with normal code.
```